# Error while printing excel cell value in python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am new to python.  Recently I am trying to work with excel files using openpyxl in windows 7.  I am trying to print the values of each cell in an excel file 'Sample.xlsx'.  Here is my code:

```
import openpyxl
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('Sample.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.active
for row in worksheet.rows:
    for col in worksheet.columns:
        cell = worksheet.cell(row = row, column = col)
        print(cell.value)
```

When I run the script I have the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "excel.py", line 6, in 
>       cell = worksheet.cell(row = row, column = col)
>     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 306, in cell
>       if row < 1 or column < 1:
>   TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() < int()

I could not understand the error. Anyone please explain what I did wrong.

Comment: What do you think `row` and `col` are in the loops you create?

Comment: I use row and col to iterate through each row and column of the work sheet.  The outer loop meant for each row of the sheet and the inner loop meant for each column of the sheet.

Comment: So, why do you think you can pass them into the `cell` method?

Comment: I misunderstood the real meaning of worksheet.rows and worksheet.columns.  Now I understood how to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`worksheet.cell` expects 1-based indexes for its `row` and `column` arguments, but you pass both a tuple (`worksheet.rows` and `worksheet.columns` each return a tuple of tuples).

You have few options:

1. Take advantage of the fact that `workbook.rows` iterates the worksheet row-wise and returns a tuple of cells for each row. This also save you a call to `worksheet.cell`:

   ```
   for row in worksheet.rows:
       for cell in row:
           print(cell.value)
   ```

   The same, but column-wise:

   ```
   worksheet = workbook.active
   for column in worksheet.columns:
       for cell in column:
           print(cell.value)
   ```
2. Use `max_row` and `max_column` to get the index (1-based) of the max row and column that are used in this sheet, and then iterate over them with `range` (while keeping in mind that `range` by default is zero-based and exclusive:

   ```
   for row in range(1, worksheet.max_row + 1):
       for col in range(1, worksheet.max_column + 1):
           cell = worksheet.cell(row = row, column = col)
           print(cell.value)
   ```
3. Use `worksheet.get_cell_collection` to get an iterable with all the used cells, saving you the need to explicitly call `worksheet.cell`.

   **The problem with this approach is that the order of the returned iterable is arbitrary**:

   ```
   for cell in worksheet.get_cell_collection():
      print(cell.value)
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much DeepSpace.  I used your option 2 after I posted the question.  Now i am able to print the values of each cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `worksheet.rows` with `worksheet.iter_rows(min_row, max_row)` and replacing `worksheet.columns` with `worksheet.iter_cols(min_col, max_col)` where the min and maxes are the loop ranges. I think `worksheet.rows` is giving a tuple and you can't use that for a `for` loop. `iter_rows()` and `iter_cols()` returns generators so it should work.

Comment: `worksheet.rows` and `worksheet.columns` are wrappers round the respective generators.

Comment: worksheet.iter_rows() and worksheet.iter_cols() also works without arguments.  by default they take worksheet.min_row / worksheet.min_column  and worksheet.max_row / worksheet.max_column as arguments

Answer (score 0):

I have tried various ways to print the values of cells in an excel sheet.  Here are the code that i tried:

```
    import openpyxl
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('Sample.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.active
    for row in range(1,worksheet.max_row+1):
        for col in range(1,worksheet.max_column+1):
            print(worksheet.cell(row=row, column=col).value)

    import openpyxl
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('Sample.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.active
    for row in worksheet.rows:
        for cell in row:
            print(cell.value)

    import openpyxl
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('Sample.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.active
    for row in worksheet.iter_rows(worksheet.min_row, worksheet.max_row):
        for cell in row:
            print(cell.value)
```